# Is my floating bridge set up properly?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar

[image]

This is a yamaha rgx220zdmg i've recently bought.

i'm not sure if the floating bridge is set up properly because this is my first time owning an electric guitar.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Completely impossible to tell from that photo. Does it play properly? if so, then it's likely fine.

Answer (score 1):

The general guidance is that the trem should be parallel with the body, however there are numerous reasons for wanting it tilted back more or forwards, so as @Tetsujin commented, if it plays well for you then it is likely to be fine.

If you tighten the trem springs at the back, the trem will be pulled flatter/closer to the body of the guitar, which will lower the height of the strings, which may be what you want, or you may prefer them to be higher. Either way, the string length and intonation will also be slightly altered if you do, so will need to be adjusted again.